# Using arithmetic operators and/or brackets in a LIMIT clause

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, limit

I have the following small subquery in query in stored procedure.

```sql
(select f_cnt from results limit (i-1)*10,i*10)
```

But there is the syntax error:

> "(" is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

So, the question is: do I have a possibility to use brackets and/or arithmetic operators in LIMIT clause?

Documentation says I can use local variables in LIMIT clause within stored procedure. Do I really need to declare and set different variables for this case?

Just in case, [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9fab0ed884b04f7cf540e09a1109858f) for the code of stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do arithmetic at that point

So do  instead

```
SET @sql := CONCAT("SELECT * FROM TEsttable WHERE id In(select f_cnt from results limit ",(i-1) * 10,",",i*10,")");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Which will produce

```
SELECT * FROM TEsttable WHERE id In(select f_cnt from results limit 90,100)
```

Comment: ehm... Ok, I think I understood what kind of mechanics you're suggesting. But I don't yet know how these statements work.
Actually, my topic is not an issue, because I've passed through syntax error with two additional variables. Still, the question about `LIMIT` clause is open.

Comment: @Gennadiy prepared statemenets like this work like any other prepared statement, you can add to the query where you want data a ? and add to the execute part the variables see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html only Limit and offet doesn't work that way, it has to be done like teh answer

Comment: it looks like useful approach, I'll learn deeper. Thanks